# Form Entry Using PHP to Store in MySQL and Return Entered Value

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is my first post, so I apologize if it's a repeat. I'm at a bit of a loss here and can't figure out why the information I've entered isn't showing when I submit it to the form. It's only my second week using PHP, but I'm trying to have the info that is entered into the form stored in MySQL and show up on the user's screen.

```
    <?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=ssl; port=8889', $user, $pass);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $fruitname = $_POST['fruitname'];
    $fruitcolor = $_POST['fruitcolor'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO fruits (fruitname, fruitcolor) VALUES (:fruitname, :fruitcolor);");

    $stmt->bindParam(':fruitname', $fruitname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fruitcolor', $fruitcolor);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

The following is the HTML for the table I've set up to display the information

```
<!-----HTML FORM ENTRY----->          
<!DOCTYPE html>     

<html lang="en">     

<head>          
    <meta charset="UTF-8">     
    <title>Fruit Database Application</title>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">          
</head>
          <body>
          <h1>Database Test</h1>
          <section class="formStyle">          
    <form action="fruits.php" method="post">     
        <label>     
            <b>Fruit Name:</b><input type="text" name="fruitname" value="" required>     
        </label><br/><br/>     
        <label><b>Fruit Color:</b><input type="text" name="fruitcolor" value="" required>     
        </label><br/><br/>     
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">     
    </form>          </section>          <br/>          <section class="tableStyle">          
    <table>     
        <thead>     
        <tr>     
            <th>Fruit ID</th>     
            <th>Fruit Name</th>     
            <th>Fruit Color</th>     
            <th>Action</th>     
        </tr>     
        </thead>          
        <tbody>
```

And this is the last bit of PHP entered into the table

```
<?php
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM fruits order by fruitId ASC;');

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row){
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['fruitId'] . '</td><td>' . $row['fruitName'] . '</td><td>' . $row['fruitColor'] . '</td><td><a href="deletefruit.php?id=' . $row['fruitId'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    }
    ?>


    </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

What I can't seem to get to show up is the info entered into the form. If I submit the name and color, and refresh my SQL database, the info shows up, so it's entering it correctly. Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what os are you using ?

Comment: I'm using OS X El Capitan 10.11.2. Sequel Pro for the database, and IntelliJ IDEA 15 for the editor.

Comment: Try writing your table names in row['tablename'] exactly as it is in database structure, because it might be case sensitive :) and yout html closing tag is not good <tr> shoud end with </tr> :) If it insertes correctly then your table names are lowercase :)

Comment: Some more background info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @MarkoMackic that was it! I was going cross-eyed looking at it too long :] Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer :) so others can see where was the mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using os different then windows , than mysql identifiers are case sensitive :) , since your addition to table went well, they're lowercase

Here is code for retrieving info corrected :

```
<?php
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM fruits order by fruitId ASC;');

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row){
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row['fruitid'] . '</td><td>' . $row['fruitname'] . '</td><td>' . $row['fruitcolor'] . '</td><td><a href="deletefruit.php?id=' . $row['fruitid'] . '">Delete</a></td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
```